# The seaborn not saving the whole figure but only part of it

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I used seaborn in python to plot and save a figure. In the jupyter notebook it looks like this.

[Whole figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pZnX.png)

But when I use the following code to save the figure, it shows like this.
[Only part of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rp0Z.jpg)

I don't know why. This is my python code.

```
whole_pt = whole_rules_df.pivot_table(index='whole_rules_from', columns='whole_rules_to', values='whole_rules_value', aggfunc=np.sum)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
one_heat = sns.heatmap(whole_pt, fmt="d",cmap='YlGnBu', ax=ax,vmin=0,vmax=1)
one_heat.get_figure().savefig('whole_rules.jpg')
```

Answer (score 14):

The matplotlib figure itself is the figure which is cropped. However, when a matplotlib figure is displayed in the inline backend with jupyter, what is shown is a saved png version of the figure. This "saving" is performed using the `bbox_inches="tight"` option, which enlarges or crops the saved region to the content of the figure.

To achieve the same when manually saving the figure, this option also has to be included,

```
fig.savefig("filename.png", bbox_inches="tight")
```

Alternatively it could be useful to directly produce a figure with the content fitting into is. This can be done using the `fig.subplots_adjust()` method or by calling `fig.tight_layout()`.